# Tomato seedlings drooping after being placed outside

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, tomatoes, seedlings

[image]

I don’t know what happened to my tomato seedlings. I just left them outside the balcony and when I checked them after 1 hour, they were all drooping.

I already moved them inside my room. Please help me, I’m a first timer and I am really clueless.

Comment: Welcome, they look quite alright to me.

Comment: Usually they are standing upright but like they are bending somehow right now. Is it alright? Or like normal?

Comment: Were they in sunlight when outdoors? What's the temperature outside, is it colder or hotter than indoors (you've not said where you are so  we don't know)

Comment: Please read up on 'hardening off' seedlings.

Comment: May we ask where in the world you are?

Comment: I’m from the Philippines :) My tomato seedlings are doing fine already. Thank you all for the advices 

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the seedlings are bending because they were buffeted by wind or were stretching towards the sun due to poor sun exposure. In either case, this won't hurt them as they grow although, if the bending is caused by limited sunlight, then that could be an issue if you're planning on growing them on the balcony.